# How to Call initWithFrame of Objective C UIView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

This is how I called the UIView **DraggableViewBackground** in Obejective C and it is working perfectly but how to do the same in Swift

```
 DraggableViewBackground *draggableBackgroundforurl = [[DraggableViewBackground alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
```

My DraggableViewBackground is in Objective C
and I want set this as a subview on click of a button

Answer (score 9):

```
let draggableBackgroundforurl = DraggableViewBackground(frame: self.view.frame);
```

That should do the trick.

You can look up the difference between `let` and `var` to decide what works best for your needs in that case. `let` can't change, `var` can.

Comment: Thank you for the help and can you tell me what if initwithframe has extra parameters

Comment: Something like  this DraggableViewBackground(frame: self.view.frame, param1: something, param2: somethingElse)

Answer (score 7):

From the [UIView docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/initWithFrame:). Just use the normal swift initializer.

[image]

Comment: Would you add an example, please (pure theory is not enough).